# Pandas writes only part of the code in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

my dictionary looks like this(shortened version):

```
my_dict = {('random_number_1', 'random_number_2'): {'random_string_1': 
'random_number_3'}, ('random_number_1', 'random_number_4'): 
{'random_string_2': 'random_number_5'}, ('random_number_1', 
'random_number_6'): {'random_string_3': 'random_number_7', 
'random_string_4': 'random_number_8', 'random_string_5': 
'random_number_9'}}

{('random_number_10','random_number_11'): {'random_string_6': 
'random_number_12', 'random_string_7': 'random_number_13'}}
```

I convert this dict to a dataframe with:

```
newdict = {(k1, k2):v2 for k1,v1 in my_dict.items() \
                   for k2,v2 in my_dict[k1].items()}

df = (pd.DataFrame( [newdict[i] for i in sorted(newdict)],
                index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([i for i in sorted(newdict.keys())]))
    .reset_index(level=1) 
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'string',0:'number'})) 
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index) 
print df
df.to_excel()
```

and I get a print out that looks like:[image: print df]

And when I try to write it to excel with df.to_excel(). It only writes out the last part of the code, so the last group of data from "string" and "number"  in my dataframe. example for better visualization : [image: What is written in excel].

Anyone has any ideas where is the problem? I would like to have whole dataframe in excel. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In you sample code

```
{('random_number_10','random_number_11'): {'random_string_6': 'random_number_12', 'random_string_7': 'random_number_13'}}
```

is not connected to any variable.

Your DataFrame looks like this (I shortened the strings to get a complete print on the console):

```
df: 
        string number
r_n_1 r_n_2  r_s_1  r_n_3
      r_n_4  r_s_2  r_n_5
      r_n_6  r_s_3  r_n_7
      r_n_6  r_s_4  r_n_8
      r_n_6  r_s_5  r_n_9
```

I cannot test with excel, but with `df.to_csv('test.csv')` your code seems to work. Content of test.csv:

```
    ,,string,number
r_n_1,r_n_2,r_s_1,r_n_3
r_n_1,r_n_4,r_s_2,r_n_5
r_n_1,r_n_6,r_s_3,r_n_7
r_n_1,r_n_6,r_s_4,r_n_8
r_n_1,r_n_6,r_s_5,r_n_9
```

Imported in LibreOffice:
[image]

Comment: Yeah but only for the first set of data, not whole.

Comment: If i print my dict, I get output like that, Maybe thats why it only prints the last one.

Comment: I think the sample code in your question is not the same you are using with your local script. The DataFrame is created just with the numbers as shown in the answer. The other numbers are not part of your dictionary, and therefor not part of the created DataFrame.
And please rename the variable 'dict' to 'mydict' or something else. 'dict' is a reserved keyword of Python itself. When using it to assign a variable you get funny side effects.

Comment: thanks for advice! I think that's the problem as well, since they are multiple dictionaries in my variable. and it only print one to excel. And I have no idea how to fix it.